# How to keep spring boot continue conncect rabbitmq server until succeeds

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Due to some complex reasons, my spring boot app needs to start before Rabbitmq server starts.

Using spring boot initializer to generate a simple spring boot app with AMQP, add corresponding configuration and @RabbitListener to listen certain queue.

If Rabbitmq server already runs, app connects with server sunccessfully;

If app starts first, then starts Rabbitmq server, the logs shows below exceptions in sequences which repeat several times and app exits

--No route to host

--Connection refused

--ACCESS_REFUSED

I also checked what comments said and found no solution.

Is there any way to keep spring boot app try to connect rabbitmq server until succeeds?

Comment: Refer https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/ in 'Adding Retry Capabilities' Section.

Comment: You can find related configuration of Rabbit MQ for retry mechanism here: [Common application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

Comment: The container will continue to reconnect indefinitely, at the `recoveryInterval` for all errors except for authentication errors, which are considered fatal.

Comment: @GaryRussell so two questions: 1)How many authetication errors are allowable? 2)Why there are authentication error while not when server starts first

Comment: 1) Authentication errors are considered fatal; there are no retries. 2) You won't get an authentication error unless the broker is running (and rejects the credentials). If the broker is down, we keep trying to reconnect after 5 seconds by default. If you are seeing different behavior, post the log someplace.

Answer (score 0):

to set SimpleMessageListenerContainer recoveryInterval to 10000L resolves the issue